# "For one who is dead, birth is certain." Counter arguments

Tags: life, eastern-philosophy

The Bhagavad Gita Chapter: 2 Verse: 27 says,  "For one who is born, death is certain. For one who is dead, birth is certain. Therefore, you should not grieve over that which is inevitable."

Statement **1**:  "For one who is born, death is certain."

Statement **2**:  "For one who is dead, birth is certain."

I couldn't find any counter arguments to Statement 2. Is there any **logical counter-argument** to put forward to this statement? **If 'yes', what is it?**

If a person is **quite sure** about the first statement/idea only, I must believe that he has clear vision at least about the two ends--**birth, death** or **the direction**...i.e., the direction is 'from birth'...**never** 'from death'...or the direction is 'to death'...**never** 'to birth'.

When he says the second statement is **uncertain**, I must believe that he is not sure about the three terms (Birth, death & the direction).

When he says the second statement is **wrong**, I must believe that he is treating the words as physical level only.

*I mean, in this case, he will be compelled to say **both are wrong** or **both are uncertain** or **both are true**...he can't stick to one statement only*.

**That is, if he says the second statement is wrong or uncertain, he can't even say the first statement is true.**

Just for comparison, think about the rain and the formation of clouds. Most people see the rain coming down. They never see the process of evaporation.

[This question is not based on the Ultimate Truth. Here birth and death should be treated above physical level.]

Comment: **logical counter arguments** to [Reincarnation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reincarnation) ?

Comment: It's hard to logically argue someone out of a position they weren't logically argued into.

Comment: You are asking for a logical counter-argument to the proposition "For one who is dead, birth is certain"?

Comment: Th logical counter argument is "there is no empirical evidence to support the notion that the dead are reborn, and so no reason to suppose that actually occurs". Same as the "logical counter argument" to the assertion that "a fine porcelain teacup orbits Saturn".

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA:Thanks for the link. Needn't confine it as 'Reincarnation'. Please don't put any restriction to enter this question...use as common words.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49713/discussion-on-question-by-sonofthought-for-one-who-is-dead-birth-is-certain).

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to use logic there is no counter argument as these are just propositions. As there's no argument there's nothing much to counter.

I can see two ways in which you could offer a counter.

One would be if you are assuming that the argument is *for one who is born, death is certain **therefore** for one who is dead, birth is certain*. This is just poor logic as *if X then Y* does not imply *if Y then X*.

The other way is if you argue that the words have meaning. In which case there is plenty of evidence that would suggest that *for one who is born, death is certain* is likely to be true. There is currently no evidence that *for one who is dead, birth is certain*. Whether or not the lack of evidence bothers you is a separate matter.

Answer (score -2):

I will throw an axe and see if it sticks for you.

Everything transforms. Usually we think of energy converting to a new form of energy or chemical reactions. Birth is a transformation but by definition in our language, is usually spoken about when speaking of life. For example, you would not say my new car is being born next month at the factory. Thus, when you die you are guaranteed not to be reborn (unless the CPR works out), although you may transform into other things, not the least of which is worm food, gases and decayed matter. Given enough time and when the universe is past being a cold dead empty place, you will not even be energy any longer. Depending on your beliefs, my argument falls apart if you consider an afterlife or your definition of birth is somewhat lateral. Be in peace that the worm food helped the birth of others.

Comment: There seems to be a lot going on in this, but I'm not sure it's a well focused answer to the question as asked.